# How to hide headings for inactive sheet, vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to hide headings for inactive sheet in the same workbook. The below code works only for active sheet

```
ActiveWindow.Displayheadings = False
```

I tried to replace activewindow with sheet name but not works

Answer (score 0):

`Displayheadings` is a `Window` property, so it will not work for a sheet.

1. Use the `Workbook_SheetActivate` event in the next way:

a. Declare a `Boolean` variable on top of `ThisWorkbook` code module (on the declarations side):

```
Public isAdmin As Boolean
```

b. Copy the next event code in `ThisWorkbook` code module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal sh As Object)
   If Not isAdmin Then
        ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False
    Else
       ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = True
   End If
End Sub
```

Making the other sheets window `Displayheadings = False` is abstract, since you cannot see how the headings look in a not activated one...

c. In order to change the `isAdmin` you may try something like this:

```
Sub makeAdmin()
    If Application.userName = "your name" Then
        isAdmin = True
    Else
       isAdmin = False
    End If
End Sub
```

This sub may be called from `Workbook_Open` event or from anywhere in your code...

Comment: Actually I try to avoid Activate on my codes , bacause of slowdown

Comment: @Waleed_wwm The, try it, but it is not possible. You need **a window** to change its property, I'm afraid... I started preparing the way using the event, which will act each time when the sheet is activated. Do you want seeing it? I will delete the code dealing with all sheets.

Comment: @FaneDure I am afraid ,as this question has no answer to my needs , I have to delete it .

Comment: @Waleed_wwm Do it as you want. But try looking to the second part of the answer, please...

Comment: What is your intention to set `DisplayHeadings` of an inactive worksheet? Will you have multiple windows which will show the inactive worksheet? @Waleed_wwm

Comment: @Raymond Wu my workbook has many sheets , my need is to automate hide headings for them without activating

Comment: Unless you have multiple windows that has other worksheet as its `ActiveSheet`, there is no point setting `DisplayHeadings` of those worksheets when it's not going to be seen at all. So do you have multiple windows at a time and you need to hide the headings of the inactive `windows`'s worksheet? @Waleed_wwm

Comment: @Waleed_wwm But, the above code works only when the sheet is activated. It takes milliseconds to hide/unhide the headings...